# Accessing folder in android

Tags: java, android

I am working on an android app in which I need to detect the language of user's input text.
So using Stackoverflow I found a recommendation of using a java library called langdetect which requires reading languages profiles.

I was able to create a simple plane java project, by adding a directory (folder) inside the java project called "profiles" which contains all the languages profiles.

I couldn't make this work in android since the only 2 ways I know of accessing files in android either by adding the desired files inside "assets" or "rec/raw" but I keep getting error saying file not found.

The method from langdetect jar file that requires reading profiles is the following

```
String path = "profiles";

DetectorFactory.loadProfile(path);
```

the above code works in plain java.

Any help guys.

I used the following
Uri.parse("android.resource://com.my.package.my.app/raw");
file:///android_asset
classLoader.getResource("profiles");

and many others in the same style.

The problem is that I don't need to access specific file per say, the only thing I need is a path to the folder that contains the languages profiles, the folder contains 53 files for 53 languages.

Comment: what is the approach you have tried so far nad what is casing you trouble?

Answer (score 0):

`path` is relative. It does not make sense in Android. You should refere the Internal/External storage with Absolute Path. If you put your data inside the sdcard, for instance, you can retrieve the Absolute Path with `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`. If you want to embeded your data inside the apk, using the `assets`  or  `raw` folder, you need the `AssetsManager` in the former case, `getResources()` in the latter.